# How to get okta user details/current session once authenticated in JAVA

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, openid-connect, okta, okta-api

In my JAVA web application, i am moving from redhat redhat SSO to OKTA.

I am able to redirect to OKTA server login page when my application URL is hit in the URL.OKTA server is being authenticated with the username and password entered and my application is redirecting to.

Now I am trying to find how to get that authenticated session or authenticated user details in java code.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I guess, it depends on the library/SDK you are using, but from web-api perspective you can just call `/userinfo` endpoint on your authorization server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, /userinfo helped me and got the user details from userinfo endpoint. Thank you Philipp.